# Can I sell a CSA approved product in the US at retail or over the internet?

Tags: ac, ul

I have a product that was designed to sell in the RV market.  The RV industry does not require require UL per se, just a "recognized listing" which can be from a number of agencies including CSA (to Canadian standards, not like CSA testing to US standards).  Given that, we normally use Canadian approvals since some RV's ship to Canada and Canada DOES require their own listing, not just "a listing".

I now have an electrical product that I want to liquidate in the US via internet or retail, but it has only CSA approval.  Will this be a issue legally?  I understand that some (many) retailers would not be comfortable selling w/o a UL or equivalent mark.  I'm wondering from a "can I" perspective, not a "should I" perspective...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Check with the retailer and see if they consider CSA as "equivalent" to UL. My guess is they'll be okay with it.

Answer (score 2):

CSA is an NRTL for US testing. Often products will be tested for both Canada and the USA, and products which have passed these test will bear the CSA mark with some US indication (cCSAus, CSAus, CSA/NRTL, etc.) - for example:

[image]

A CSA mark without a US indication is technically *not valid* for the US, even though the standards are largely identical between the countries. End users would get in trouble if the units you're selling cause any damage, with the onus on them to have had special inspection from UL (or some other NRTL) in order to get insurance payouts.